# I 'm new to zend 3 . When i'm installed zend and hit the url (localhost/zf3/public) then i got this error

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Fatal error: Method Zend\View\Helper\HeadTitle::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Zend\I18n\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException: Zend\I18n\Translator component requires the intl PHP extension in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf3\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml on line 0

Comment: I don't know more about zend framework. So plss help me

Comment: What's unclear about "*requires the intl PHP extension*"?

Comment: You should use PHP7.4, as that now allows for throwing exceptions in `__toString()` methods ([reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.tostring-exceptions)). That said, the exception will still come, but it won't be `__toString() must not throw an exception`. As gregor above says, the message from the exception is "*component requires the intl PHP extension*", which is your actual error.

Comment: https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncomment (remove `;` character) in this line:

```
;extension=intl
```

in your `php.ini` file (and restart apache / nginx if you are using any webserwer).